# Python SQLAlchemy - Error IM001 reflecting table

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

first of all, sorry if I'm not writing in the right place or I'm not providing enough info about the issue.

Using SQL Alchemy, with pyodbc. I'm trying to reflect a table.
When I try to do that, i get this message

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM001', '[IM001] [unixODBC][Driver
>   Manager]Driver does not support this function (0) (SQLNumParams)')
>   [SQL: u'SELECT [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA], [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME],
>   [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_NAME], [COLUMNS_1].[IS_NULLABLE],
>   [COLUMNS_1].[DATA_TYPE], [COLUMNS_1].[ORDINAL_POSITION],
>   [COLUMNS_1].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH],
>   [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_PRECISION], [COLUMNS_1].[NUMERIC_SCALE],
>   [COLUMNS_1].[COLUMN_DEFAULT], [COLUMNS_1].[COLLATION_NAME] \nFROM
>   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] AS [COLUMNS_1] \nWHERE
>   [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_NAME] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) AND
>   [COLUMNS_1].[TABLE_SCHEMA] = CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)) ORDER BY
>   [COLUMNS_1].[ORDINAL_POSITION]'] [parameters: ('Order', 'dbo')]

Here is the code..

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
>>> from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
>>> import sqlalchemy as SQLA
>>> eng = SQLA.create_engine(connection_string)
>>> session = Session(eng.connect())
>>> class DB:
...     pass
... 
>>> db = DB()
>>> db.session = session
>>> db.engine = eng
>>> db.metadata = MetaData(bind=db.engine, schema='dbo')
>>> db.session.execute("select * from information_schema.columns")
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x7f76eb770890>
>>> t = SQLA.Table('Order', db.metadata, autoload=True, extend_existing=True, autoload_with=db.engine)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
...   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ... See the error above
```

The code is running on a RHEL 7.x with unixODBC, Microsoft SQL Server Native clinet 11 for Linux.  Python 2.7.11

Here are the pip requirements

- click (6.6) db-connection-maker (1.2.0)
- Flask (0.11.1)
- itsdangerous (0.24)
- Jinja2 (2.8)
- MarkupSafe (0.23)
- pip (8.0.2)
- pyaml (15.8.2)
- pyodbc (3.0.10)
- PyYAML (3.11)
- setuptools (19.6.2)
- simplejson (3.8.2)
- SQLAlchemy (1.0.14)
- Werkzeug (0.11.10)

Note that the same code works without issues on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a try with **pymmsql** and it works without issues. The problem was on *pyodbc*, maybe it still have some problems with **ms sql odbc drivers on Linux**.